# need dom element containg angularjs directive to be destroyed and created again so that directive's compile and link functions run again

Tags: angularjs, directive, destroy, rebuild

i have custom angular directive 'my-directive' as follows:

`<div my-directive>
    <div ng-repeat="image in images">
        <img ng-src="{{image.url}}"/>
    </div>
</div>`

what my-directive does is in it's link function gets the element to which it is applied and initializes jquery carousel plugin on that element. 
My issue is that when i click on button with click handler setting `scope.images` to another value then carousel is broken. So in button click handler after i set `scope.images` to another value i want to do some action which will cause the dom element to be destroyed and created again. In that case directive's link function will run again and the carousel will be initialized with new images.

Ideally i should not make any change to directive itself because it is a generic directive used in multiple places and in different situations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you can't restart the plugin rather than the directive? What is the plugin exactly? And show some relevant code of the directive